# Jquery ui sortable drop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with jquery ui sortable. 
I would like to get the sorting array to pass it to the handling file on drop event.

one funny thing i found..
http://jsfiddle.net/7Ny9h/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    $( "#sortable li" ).droppable({
        drop: function( ) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {key:'order[]'});
            $( "p" ).html( order );
        }
    });
});
```

Seeing the sample, if I move BOX No.2, the BOX 2 is left out of the array.

Perhaps I need a kind of "dropend" event because it seems that jquery ui drop event doesn't count the dragged and dropped one.

Answer (score 48):

You can also use `update` to detect it.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    update: function( ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This is most likely the better option (instead of 'stop') if you are looking to do some kind of "on success" type of message instead of a general "on finish moving".

Comment: Is it possible to determine what li element was moved to invoke the update call?

Answer (score 29):

I could solve the problem with jQuery UI Sortable `stop` event.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        stop: function( ) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {key:'order[]'});
            $( "p" ).html( order );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Prozi, that's because you're doing it wrong. Your JSfiddle in your comment doesn't actually change the "droppable" event to the "sortable" one. This is why it was failing on you, I've updated your JSfiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/a94fak79/

Comment: See @SoursopTree's answer below for a very simple solution that worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

When using with multiple sortable lists on a single page where you also need to save the order of both lists as well as what items were moved into which list, only the stop() method works. All other events fire twice or more when elements are moved from one list into another.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        stop: function( ) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {key:'order[]'});
            $( "p" ).html( order );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that needs to specifically access the LI element that triggered the update function like I did, (from the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27372951/16393363)) you can do so with the adjustments below:

```
// Simply include the event in the function parameters
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    update: function(ev) {
        // ev.originalEvent.target is the target that was clicked to drag the li inside the sortable (ev.target is the sortable ul itself)
        // In case you have subelements in your li, call a recursive function that moves up in the DOM until it hits an LI
        var li_elem = getLI(ev.originalEvent.target);
        // Do work using the li element that triggered this event below!
    }
});

// Recursive function to get the LI element
function getLI(elem) {
    // If we have the LI return
    if (elem.tagName === "LI") {
        return(elem);
    }
    // If not check the parent
    const parent = elem.parentElement;
    if (parent.tagName != "LI") {
        // If still not LI element, recall function but pass in the parent elemtn
        return(getLI(parent));
        
    }
    else {
        // Return the parent if it's the LI element
        return(parent);
    }
}
```